# Custom logic for MachForms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to be able to add some custom logic to my MachForm that doesn't seem to be supported out-of-the-box. The thing I need help with is figuring out **where** to place an onSubmit function for my custom form. Here's the code I plan on implementing:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    //var dollars = $('[name="element_15_2"]').val();
    //var cents = $('[name="element_15_3"]').val();
    //var conv = parseFloat(dollars + '.' + cents);

    var dollars = parseInt($('[name="element_15_2"]').val());
    var cents = parseInt($('[name="element_15_3"]').val());
    var conv = dollars + (cents / 100);
    var total = (+(Math.round((conv * 1.0425) + "e+2") + "e-2")).toString();
    var currencies = total.split(/\./);
    $('[name="element_15_2"]').val(currencies[0]);
    $('[name="element_15_3"]').val(currencies[1]);
});
```

In case anyone was wondering, element_15_2 and 15_3 both comprise a Price fieldtype in MachForms.

In any case, I've searched the directory that is named after my form but the only things present are a CSS file and an index.html, neither of which contain anything useful (the index being completely blank).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using parseInt to get two integers, then add them together? `dollars + (cents / 100)`

Comment: No. Would there be a performance boost?

Comment: You wouldn't need the string concatenation, but the efficiency change would be minor.  I just thought it was odd that you did it that way.

Comment: Ah. I just figured that since the values come in as strings and parseFloat expects a string, just concat with the . inside the call and be done.

Comment: It works, sure.  parseInt also takes strings and doing the division math is *probably* faster than the string concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, I was able to find that the script I have here will work in an external JS file and can be added to a specific MachForm via "Load Custom Javascript File" in Form Properties (in Edit mode).

Before I figured this out, I was looking at possibly modifying the mf_display_form function in view-functions.php (which may be a viable alternative, I did not test it).

Comment: As an aside: if you plan on doing more significant customizations to MachForm's JavaScript, you may want to contact their support team for an unobfuscated set of JS files to work with.  I've done this several times in the past (having customized MachForm very extensively), and they've been really good about it.  Don't do what I did the first time and start customizing the obfuscated version. :)

Comment: Thankfully, I didn't have to modify their JS directly but that's good to know. Next on my list is some custom validation which WILL require me to modify post-functions.php, I believe.

Comment: Ah, cool.  I don't think I've modified post-functions.php before - mostly stuff in view-functions.php and some others, regarding things like adding new fields and adding new options to existing fields.